# How to set the orientation of a UWP app programmatically

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am developing a UWP Application for a physical device that can be accessed from two sides (display is facing up). The default orientation is Landscape and I would like to be able to flip (rotate by 180°) the orientation of the application programmatically.

I already tried two different things:

### 1. Change the Windows display orientation using the Win32 API

For this, you need to use API functions contained in user32.lib, which cannot be done / is not allowed from a UWP application. Therefore, I wrote a separate program that could be triggered from the UWP application. Here you can see how I implemented the display orientation based on the code provided with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25652812/10713939):

```
#include <windows.h>

bool SetDisplayOrientation(bool flip) {
    int index = 0;
    DISPLAY_DEVICE dd;
    dd.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
    while (EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, index++, &dd, 0) && !(dd.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_PRIMARY_DEVICE));

    DEVMODE dm;
    ZeroMemory(&dm, sizeof(dm));
    dm.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
    if (!EnumDisplaySettings(dd.DeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dm)) {
        return false;
    }
    dm.dmDisplayOrientation = flip ? DMDO_180 : DMDO_DEFAULT;

    dm.dmFields = (DM_DISPLAYORIENTATION);
    if (ChangeDisplaySettings(&dm, CDS_TEST) != DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL) {
        return false;
    }

    return (ChangeDisplaySettings(&dm, 0) == DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL);
}
```

This works, but when I run the UWP app in Windows 10's Kiosk mode (as we intend to do), it hides the application after the rotation, showing a blank screen if I interacted with the UI before (no clue why that happens either, looks like a bug to me). If I didn't interact with the UI, the rotation works just fine, but that's no solution...

### 2. Use the DXGI swap chain to rotate the app?

Googling for solutions I quickly came across [IDXGISwapChain1::SetRotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgiswapchain1-setrotation) and also found [this example program](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/DXGI-swap-chain-rotation-21d13d71). But this all together seems to not be the correct solution for a simple UWP user interface as we would need to implement our UI using DirectX. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

### 3. Change AutoRotationPreferences

I also tried executing the following command on a button press, but it did not do anything:

```
DisplayInformation^ displayInformation = DisplayInformation::GetForCurrentView();
displayInformation->AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations::LandscapeFlipped;
```

---

Is there any way to force the orientation of a UWP app without changing the display orientation of windows?

Comment: It will be running in fullscreen at all times

Answer (score 0):

The **AutoRotationPreferences** api you used is only designed to work when the device is in Tablet mode,so it doesn't work in your device.You could consider setting the screen rotation using **SetDisplayConfig** from a Win32 app on startup and I will also do some tests for that.